# Is LOESS the appropriate way of visualizing my RT data?

Tags: r, regression, smoothing, ggplot2

I am conducting a [Lexical Decision Task](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_decision_task) where my dependent random variable is Response Time (RT).

My experimental design consists of 5 blocks of a 100 trials each. In each block, 50% of trials correspond to one experimental condition, and the other 50% to the other experimental condition. Order of presentation or trials in randomized.

I am using the R programming language to do my analysis

When I plotted the average RT per block, per condition, I saw that the difference between my conditions was quite prominent, whereas I expected differences to be small at first, and then become larger as blocks advanced.

In order to see more in detail how the RT were changing across trials, I plotted RT across trials instead of blocks. Now, since there were a lot of data points, I had to use a smoothing technique called [LOESS](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmd/section1/pmd144.htm). This indeed smoothed the data pretty nicely but:

1) Apparently it made me loose data. When using the stat_smooth() function in R, it warned me of missing values:

```
1: Removed 31 rows containing missing values (stat_smooth). 
2: Removed 3 rows containing missing values (stat_smooth).
```

2) The results are again surprising, to a point where I thing I might be doing something wrong. I wanted to attach one of my plots, but I lack the reputation points to attach images. In any case, the faster condition is *always* faster, from the first trial where they appear. This doesn't make any psychological sense, and so I am wondering whether this smoothing technique is the appropriate one or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify how time comes into the experiment - you say you expected differences "to become larger as blocks advanced" - what does this mean?  Also, are you plotting the points using geom_point() or geom_jitter() as well as stat_smooth() - if so it should help for a reality check.  If there's too much data to see try something like + geom_point(alpha=0.1) to add transparency.

Comment: ah, are these repeat measurements on subjects that get multiple trials each?

Comment: @PeterEllis Yes indeed the design of the experiments is repeated measures for each participant. Each one does 5 blocks of 100 trials, with a total of 500 trials per participant. What I meant is that I expected RTs not to differ much in the first trials of block 2 (block 1 is only practice) but what I see is that RT are always different. I added geom_point() to my ggplot and now I can see the actual data points. Thanks!
Still, I wonder why I got the message that I had missing values after applying the smoothing. And is a LOESS an appropriate regression technique for this case?

Comment: This warning typically indicates that there is missing data in the data frame, not that the smoothing procedure discarded data for no reason. Are you certain that you don't have any missing entry in the data frame before calling the graphing function? This might also be some programming issue specific to ggplot (i.e. not to LOESS as a statistical technique).